# Children of U.K. Passport holder on accompaniment visas

Tags: visas, dual-nationality

I am a U.K. Passport holder and my children (13&14 yrs old) are still on South African passports(accompaniment visa as).They are now eligible to apply for U.K. Citizenship. However we want to travel to France in August( their dad is a French passport holder and we will be going to see him). What entry requirements do they need?

Answer (score 3):

To visit France with South African passports, they need Schengen visas.  They should apply as family members of an EU citizen (you) which will mean that the visas will be free of charge.

If they get UK passports before they go, they will not need visas.

As their father is French, they may also be French, so you might want to consider getting French passports for them as well.